# LaTeX Error: Command \textasciiacute unavailable in encoding T1

Tags: macros, errors

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 

\begin{document}
```

TEXT says: ".....older men´s and young women´s cohorts...."

LaTeX Error:

> Command \textasciiacute unavailable in encoding T1.

Can someone tell me how to solve it? Its not a matter of language.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX!  Just type an apostrophe instead of an acute accent.

Comment: The possessive case is marked with an [apostrophe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apostrophe).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as solved in comments

Answer (score 2):

As said in the comments you want an apostrophe instead of an accute accent.  Alternatively you can use `\rq`:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

\showoutput

Men's

Men\rq s
\end{document}
```